# Different Shapes for High Chart's Bubble Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can we customize HighChart's [Bubble Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/sfLd69je/4/) to have different Shapes.

Like if we represent 4 different event types, we not only want 4 different colors for bubbles, but also each bubble in different shape like Circle, Triangle, square etc.

Is it possible with HighCharts, if so can anyone provide small example?

If it is not possible then which JS toolkit is best for chart customization?

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$('#container').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    type: 'bubble',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bubble: {
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<b>Sai {series.name}</b><br>',
                            pointFormat: '{point.x} fatalities, {point.y} injured, {point.z}  total Sai'

                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
                },

                series: [{
                    data: [[97, 36, 79], [94, 74, 60], [68, 76, 58], [64, 87, 56], [68, 27, 73], [74, 99, 42], [7, 93, 87], [51, 69, 40], [38, 23, 33], [57, 86, 31]]
                }, {
                    data: [[25, 10, 87], [2, 75, 59], [11, 54, 8], [86, 55, 93], [5, 3, 58], [90, 63, 44], [91, 33, 17], [97, 3, 56], [15, 67, 48], [54, 25, 81]]
                }, {
                    data: [[47, 47, 21], [20, 12, 4], [6, 76, 91], [38, 30, 60], [57, 98, 64], [61, 17, 80], [83, 60, 13], [67, 78, 75], [64, 12, 10], [30, 77, 82]]
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Here is the user voice link in HC site for the same. http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3913511-allow-for-custom-symbols-when-using-bubble-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of bubble, you can use a scatter serie and define marker.

```
series: [{
        marker: {
            radius:5,
            symbol: 'triangle'
        },
        data: [
            [97, 36],
            [94, 74]
        ]
    }, {
        marker: {
            radius:5,
            symbol: 'circle'
        },
        data: [
            [25, 10],
            [2, 75]
        ]
    }, {

         marker: {
            radius:5,
            symbol: 'diamond'
        },
        data: [
            [47, 47],
            [20, 12]
        ]
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qL9ap8po/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I just looked at it.